# How to prove there is not a polynomial $P(x)$ that is a good approximation to $\cos(x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion, approximation

**The problem:**

"True or false: there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $|P(x) - \cos(x)| \leq 10^{-6}$ for all real $x$."

I know the answer (it is false) but I do not understand the proof given in the book.

**The proof:**

Suppose $P(x) = a_Nx^N + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{a_nx^n}$ where $N\geq 1$ and $a_N > 0$.
It is enough to show that $P(x) > 2$ for some value of $x$.

*(I do not understand the following steps in the proof, could someone
please explain them.)*

A number $x$ can be found so large that $a_Nx^N > N|a_n|x^n + 2$ for each integer $n$ where $0 \leq n \leq N-1$. The smallest possible value of $P(x)$ for any given positive $x$ would be achieved if all the coefficients in the sum were negative. Thus

$$ P(x) \geq a_Nx^N - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{|a_n| x^n} > a_Nx^N + (2 - a_Nx^N) = 2 $$

Link to the book (the problem in question is problem 10): https://books.openbookpublishers.com/10.11647/obp.0181.pdf

[This is the proof given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGqEn.png)

Comment: A non-constant polynomial always satisfies $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} |P(x)| = +\infty$$

Comment: Do you want the main idea or a more detailed explanation?

Comment: A more detailed explanation please.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I understand what you're saying (just by thinking of the graphs it's clear that they tend to infinity), do you know if there is a formal proof for this?

Comment: @RahulLakhanpaul Yes, if $P(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ with $a_n \neq 0$, just write $$P(x)=a_nx^n \left(1 + \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{a_k}{a_n} x^{k-n} \right)$$ The parenthesis tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, whereas $a_nx^n$ tends to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks this makes sense - should the upper limit of the sum not be $n-1$ though instead of $\infty$?

Comment: @RahulLakhanpaul Yes, of course, this is a (weird) typo.

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem to show that $P$ has infinitely many roots.